# I have written this program and have been unable to find any errors but am still not getting any output when i put my input in

Tags: javascript

This is my code. Anyone have any idea why there would be no output? I have no syntax errors being posted and it is allowing me to put in my input but after i put my input it does not display any output or error messages ..................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var basePrice, carType, salePrice, markupLow, markupMed, markupHigh;

var fordLow = 1.02;
var fordMed = 1.03;
var fordHigh = 1.05;
var GMLow = 1.05;
var GMMed = 1.07;
var GMHigh = 1.10;
var dodgeLow = 1.01;
var dodgeMed = 1.02;
var dodgeHigh = 1.03;
var highCutoff = 20000;
var lowCutoff = 10000;
var errorFlag = 0;

basePrice = prompt("What is the base price?", "10000");
basePrice = parseInt(basePrice);
carType = prompt("Which car brand? ford, gm, dodge?", "ford");

switch(carType)
{
    case "ford":
        markupLow = fordLow;
        markupMed = fordMed;
        markupHigh = fordHigh;
    break;
    case "gm":
        markupLow = gmLow;
        markupMed = gmMed;
        markupHigh = gmHigh;
    break;
    case "dodge":
        markupLow = dodgeLow;
        markupMed = dodgeMed;
        markupHigh = dodgeHigh;
    break;
    default:
        alert("You typed " + carType + " you needed to type: ford, gm, or dodge");
        errorFlag = 1;
    break;

if (errorFlag == 0)
{    
        if (basePrice > highCutoff)
      { 
              markupRate = markupHigh;
            }       
    else if (basePrice < lowCutoff)
    {    
                markupRate = markupLow
    }
        else
                {
        markupRate = markupMed;
                }

        salePrice = basePrice * markupRate;

document.write("Base Price: $" + basePrice);
document.write("<br>Car Make" + carType);
document.write("<br>The sale price: $" + salePrice);
}
else
{
        document.write("You typed " + carType + " you needed to type: ford, gm, or dodge");
}
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, it hasn't been necessary to put scripts in `<!-- -->` for many years.

Comment: You would see the problem if you indented your code properly. All code editors can do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been using hmtl kit and it inputs those by default. And i am new to coding and am not 100% with indenting yet. I understand that if my indentation was perfect i could see it easier.

Comment: I haven't used HTML Kit, but I'll bet it can indent JavaScript properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the switch statement earlier. Otherwise the rest is not executed, because of the `break` statement of `default`.

```js
var basePrice, carType, salePrice, markupLow, markupMed, markupHigh;

var fordLow = 1.02;
var fordMed = 1.03;
var fordHigh = 1.05;
var GMLow = 1.05;
var GMMed = 1.07;
var GMHigh = 1.10;
var dodgeLow = 1.01;
var dodgeMed = 1.02;
var dodgeHigh = 1.03;
var highCutoff = 20000;
var lowCutoff = 10000;
var errorFlag = 0;

basePrice = prompt("What is the base price?", "10000");
basePrice = parseInt(basePrice);
carType = prompt("Which car brand? ford, gm, dodge?", "ford");

switch (carType) {
  case "ford":
    markupLow = fordLow;
    markupMed = fordMed;
    markupHigh = fordHigh;
    break;
  case "gm":
    markupLow = gmLow;
    markupMed = gmMed;
    markupHigh = gmHigh;
    break;
  case "dodge":
    markupLow = dodgeLow;
    markupMed = dodgeMed;
    markupHigh = dodgeHigh;
    break;
  default:
    alert("You typed " + carType + " you needed to type: ford, gm, or dodge");
    errorFlag = 1;
    break;
} // close switch

if (errorFlag == 0) {
  if (basePrice > highCutoff) {
    markupRate = markupHigh;
  } else if (basePrice < lowCutoff) {
    markupRate = markupLow
  } else {
    markupRate = markupMed;
  }

  salePrice = basePrice * markupRate;

  document.write("Base Price: $" + basePrice);
  document.write("<br>Car Make" + carType);
  document.write("<br>The sale price: $" + salePrice);
} else {
  document.write("You typed " + carType + " you needed to type: ford, gm, or dodge");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I completely looked over that.

Comment: maybe you think about an object for taking the varrious values for each type. and use a loop for checking unwanted inputs ... and don't use `document.write`.